# Is there any alternative words or phrases in English for 'challenge someone to a fight with rubbing spittle on the forehead'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If you dare to smear spittle on someone's forehead, it signifies a challenge to engage in a fight. Such challenges often occur among children. When one child challenges another to a fight, they swiftly mark their opponent's forehead with their saliva as a sign of the challenge. Such tradition still persists in certain Asian cultures.

Comment: When you say "such challenges often occur among children": where exactly does this custom occur? I've never heard of it.

Comment: (Unless this custom exists in an English-speaking country, it's unlikely that there would be an established English word for it.)

Comment: There are terms for challenging to a fight but not like that. It's possible the name in a major eastern language might get some English usage in specialized contexts, if you can provide more information.

Comment: The only equivalent phrase in English, though not relating to children, is [throw down the gauntlet](https://www.history.com/news/what-does-it-mean-to-throw-down-the-gauntlet).

Comment: When I was a kid you'd challenge someone to a fight verbally, saying something like "I'm gonna fight you after school", and that was sufficient. Although other schools may have had local traditions. Certainly there's a tradition of [slapping someone with a glove](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GloveSlap) but I don't think that's done in playgrounds.

Comment: I wish people would take it easy on the dv's. I've seen much worse with tons of points...

Comment: @StuartF The glove thing is for duels. And I think it's historically related to throwing down the gauntlet.

Answer (score 1):

We do have in English the confrontational insulting phrase "Piss on you". But it is not accompanied by actual pissing and it is not, at least nowadays, a *ritualistic* challenge to a fist-fight, though it might lead to one; in centuries past it could have led to a duel at sunrise.

And here, as *lagniappe*, the [ice-cream-cone scene from Peter Weir's *Witness*](https://youtu.be/o07ecRzkLuM), a film about the "Pennsylvania Dutch" and non-violence.